QField project folder file update
I have a .gpkg file for mapping polygons, everything has worked fine, I can see the mapped polygons in QField.

When I export the local project file, the .gpkg exports as the original (un-digitised) file.
When I navigate to the project folder (In open QField project > settings wheel >  Project folder) I can see the file is the original size, so the .gpkg in QField is not updating in the project folder.

Any ideas where it might be saving to? I've check the ch.opengis.qfield folder (Android) and it is not updated here either...
